# NDK and OpenGL basics on android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am attempting to work with the NDK to render an openGL image on Android. I've taken a basic graphics course and am familiar with open GL. I have looked at several examples, such as the San-Angeles project, but have no idea what is going on. I'm familiar with calls such as glBegin(GL_LINES);. I don't see anything like that anywhere in there. There seems to be a lot of code doing a lot of things which becomes a bit overwhelming. So, are there any resources I can take advantage of that show basic openGL rendering on Android. I'm talking drawing a rotating triangle type of tutorial. If not, are there any more complicated projects like San-Angeles that are commented?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OpenGL ES (the OpenGL subset supported on Android) does not support the glBegin/glEnd method of rendering primitives. You should look into using vertex arrays instead. glDrawArrays and glDrawElements are the basic calls you need to look into.

Oh, and Khronos have some relevant information here: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/